# Upload multiple jar files to maven repository (e.g. Archiva)

Tags: maven, archiva

In one of our project we are planning to generate multiple jar files (basically libraries, which contain no dependencies) .

We would like to upload these jar files to local maven repository (Archiva looks good, we are also open to other options) so other developers can simply use them.

(Single jar file deploy works great)

PS: We are using maven.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you generate them I suppose you do that via Maven so you can already upload them via `mvn deploy`?

Answer (score 0):

When you build your jar files with Maven, you simply call `mvn deploy` (having a correct `settings.xml`) and the jar goes into your Maven repository.

If you have jars *not* built with Maven, you can use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to upload them.